# How can I drive citation tracking to include \citetitle command using biblatex?

Tags: biblatex, citing

I 'm using verbose-trad1 style. I have this result using `\cite{x}` command.
[image]

As you can see, cite tracking works fine, but if I use `\citetitle{x}` cite tracking does not work. (That's ok and, of course, it is mentioned at biblatex doc.)
What I want is to avoid citing the author, even in the first cite. But, of course, if I use \citetitle command, I lose cite tracking. Is there a way to modifiy \citetitle command to include cite tracking?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are a couple ways to do this. Enabling trackers in the definition of `\citetitle` won't give you `ibidem` and `shorthand` abbreviations without some extra work. Just omitting `labelname` from `\cite` can make a (semantic) mess of some abbreviations - namely `opcit`, `loccit` and `idem`.

The code below (hopefully) takes care of these limitations by defining a hook to suppress `labelname`, `author`, or `editor` and fix problematic abbreviations. This hook can be used in the document body or within a definition of a command.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[american]{babel}
\usepackage{csquotes}
\usepackage[style=verbose-trad1]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{biblatex-examples.bib}

\newbibmacro*{cite:full:noname}{%
  \usebibmacro{cite:full:citepages}%
  \printtext[bibhypertarget]{%
    \usedriver
      {\clearname{author}%
       \clearname{editor}}
      {\thefield{entrytype}}}%
  \usebibmacro{shorthandintro}}

\newrobustcmd*{\citetitlehook}{%
  \AtNextCite{%
    \renewbibmacro*{cite:full}{\usebibmacro{cite:full:noname}}%
    \renewbibmacro*{cite:name}{}%
    \renewbibmacro*{cite:idem}{}%
    \renewbibmacro*{cite:loccit}{\usebibmacro{cite:title}}%
    \renewbibmacro*{cite:opcit}{\usebibmacro{cite:title}}}}

\renewrobustcmd*{\citetitle}{\citetitlehook\cite}
\newrobustcmd*{\citetitles}{\citetitlehook\cites}
\newrobustcmd*{\parencitetitle}{\citetitlehook\parencite}
\newrobustcmd*{\parencitetitles}{\citetitlehook\parencites}
\newrobustcmd*{\autocitetitle}{\citetitlehook\autocite}
\newrobustcmd*{\autocitetitles}{\citetitlehook\autocites}
\newrobustcmd*{\footcitetitle}{\citetitlehook\footcite}
\newrobustcmd*{\footcitetitles}{\citetitlehook\footcites}

\begin{document}
\null\vfill\noindent
Citetitle: \citetitle{kant:kpv}.
Parencitetitle: \parencite{kant:kpv}.
Autocitetitle.\autocitetitle[10]{companion}
Footcite with recurrent entry.\footcite[10]{companion}
Footcites with recurrent entry+page.\footcites{knuth:ct,knuth:ct:a}[10]{companion}
Footcite with recurrent author.\footcite{knuth:ct,knuth:ct:a}
Footcite with hook.\citetitlehook\footcite{augustine}
Footcite with hook and recurrent entry.\citetitlehook\footcite[10]{augustine}
Footcites with hook and recurrent entry+page.\citetitlehook\footcites{knuth:ct,knuth:ct:a}[10]{augustine}
Footcite with hook and recurrent author.\citetitlehook\footcite{knuth:ct,knuth:ct:a}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: @AudreyGreat! Thank you so much. The new command `\footcitetitle` works fine, but `\citetitlehook` does not work if I want to cite inline. So I created another commmand called `\citeonlytitle` and... it worked! My question is: should `\citetitlehook` have worked or is it a kind of "private command"?

Comment: @Mario No problem. `\citetitlehook` should work in the document body. I'll revise the post to better demonstrate its range of use.

Comment: `\citetitlehook` doesn't work in my document body. But `\renewrobustcmd*{\citetitle}{\citetitlehook\cite}` (or `\newrobustcmd*{\citeonlytitle}{\citetitlehook\cite}`) solves my problem. Thanks.

Comment: @Mario Strange. Doesn't work in the example I posted, or in your actual document?

Comment: `\citetitlehook` doesn't work in my actual document. I didn't test your example, but I will (could you post your .bib file?)

Comment: @Mario I'd be curious to know why. But if troubleshooting isn't worth the effort, no worries. The `bib` file comes with the `biblatex` documentation. You can find it in `doc\latex\biblatex\examples` in your `tex` tree.

Comment: I've tested your example and I've realized that I didn't understand the way I must use `\citetitlehook`: it doesn't work alone, but like a tool to switch the biblatex commands like `\footcite`. Sorry for the misunderstanding. New commands work fine with your example and my actual document.