# biblatex citation format

Tags: biblatex, citing

I have started using LaTeX with biblatex to format my dissertation. I need my citation to look something like: (johnson, 2010:29), which is (author, year:page).

Then there are some citations that I have to make look like (Xenophon, *Hellenica* 7.6.2), which is (author, *italicized book*, section).

Is it possible to modify `\autocite` to work like this? If so... where do I start? Which file do I have to modify?

Comment: You have tag your question `biblatex`, but mention BibTeX in the title and question. The answer will likely depend on which system you are using.

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.sx!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx) You don't have to sign with your name since it automatically appears in the lower right corner of your post.

Comment: For classical citations, maybe the advice in [this answer](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/31286/how-do-i-cite-classical-works-with-biblatex/31344#31344) will be of interest..?

Comment: Thank you, Jon. I missed that one. I will give it a whirl.

Answer (score 5):

Your author-year citation command can be obtained using the `authoryear` style and some minor edits to `nameyeardelim` and the `postnote` format. A variant of this using the title in place of the year can easily be defined using the `\AtNextCite` hook.

```
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage[american]{babel}
\usepackage{csquotes}
\usepackage[style=authoryear]{biblatex}
\usepackage[colorlinks]{hyperref}

\renewcommand*{\nameyeardelim}{\nametitledelim}
\renewcommand*{\postnotedelim}{\addcolon}
\DeclareFieldFormat{postnote}{#1}

\newrobustcmd*{\citehook}{%
  \AtNextCite{%
    \renewcommand*{\postnotedelim}{\addspace}%
    \renewbibmacro*{cite:labelyear+extrayear}{%
      \iffieldundef{label}
        {\printtext[bibhyperref]{\printfield[citetitle]{labeltitle}}}
        {}}}}

\newrobustcmd*{\autocitetitle}{\citehook\autocite}
\newrobustcmd*{\autocitetitles}{\citehook\autocites}

\addbibresource{biblatex-examples.bib}
\begin{document}
\null\vfill
Filler text \autocite[See][10--15]{aristotle:poetics}.
Filler text \autocitetitle[See][7.6.2]{aristotle:poetics}.
Filler text \autocite{aristotle:poetics,aristotle:rhetoric,kant:kpv,cms}.
Filler text \autocites[10--15]{aristotle:poetics}[25]{aristotle:rhetoric}.
Filler text \autocitetitle{aristotle:poetics,aristotle:rhetoric,kant:kpv,cms}.
Filler text \autocitetitles[7.6.2]{aristotle:poetics}{aristotle:rhetoric}.
\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

[image]

An advantage of this approach is that it works for any of the author-year styles. Here's the citation output of the same document using the package options `style=authoryear-icomp` and `autocite=footnote`.

[image]

To further customize the citation label for a specific entry, you can make use of the `shorthand` and `label` fields in your bib file. In the sample document, the entry by Kant goes by the shorthand "KpV". This overrides both `labelname` and `labelyear`+`extrayear`. The Chicago Manual of Style has the label "CMS". It overrides only `labelname`.

All of the citation style changes can be incorporated into `\autocite`, but you'll have to provide some details on which entries need to be cited with titles. These can be distinguished through criteria specified on existing bibliographic data or through a category defined in your document preamble or bib file.