# remove "pp." from references produced by chicago style, re-position page numbers

Tags: bibtex, natbib, chicago-style

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}
\usepackage{amssymb,amsmath,amsthm,amsfonts}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{natbib}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{lscape}
\usepackage{dcolumn}
\usepackage{longtable}
\bibliographystyle{chicago}
\setcitestyle{notesep={: }}
```

I want to (i) remove parentheses and put full stop behind eds., (ii) change the comma after the title to a full stop, (iii) remove "pp." and put pages numbers at the back and (iv) after publisher (and before the page numbers) should be `:` rather than `.`

I guess I should go change "chicago.bst" but I do not find where I should make the changes.

```
@incollection{Ballwieser-global-history-2010,
booktitle={A Global History of Accounting, Financial Reporting and Public Policy: Europe},
author={Wolfgang Ballwieser},
title={Germany},
pages={59-88},
editor={Previts, G.J. and Walton, P.J. and Wolnizer, P.W.},
year={2010},
address={United Kingdom},
publisher={Emerald Group Publishing Limited},
}
```

> Ballwieser, W. (2010). Germany. In G. Previts, P. Walton, and P.
>   Wolnizer (Eds.), *A Global History of Accounting, Financial Reporting
>   and Public Policy: Europe*. pp. 59–88. United Kingdom: Emerald Group
>   Publishing Limited.

The following is what I am looking for

> Ballwieser, W. (2010). Germany. In G. Previts, P. Walton, and P.
>   Wolnizer, eds. *A Global History of Accounting, Financial Reporting
>   and Public Policy: Europe.* United Kingdom: Emerald Group Publishing
>   Limited: 59–88.

Comment: Just a comment: If the modifications you want to make are a result of wanting to adhere to a particular organisation's guidelines, you might find that the necessary BibTeX style exists already. Somewhere.

Answer (score 2):

In the code below, I show how you can edit the file `chicago.bst` -- rename it to `mychicago.bst` in the process, please -- to remove the string `pp.` before the page range.

For all other modifications you're looking to achieve, I think you're much better off not trying to hack an existing `.bst` file. Instead, you should look to crate a new, custom bibliography style file from scratch with the help of the `makebst` utility (part of the [custom-bib](http://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/custom-bib) package). At a command prompt, type `latex makebst` and follow the detailed prompts; at the end of the long series of prompts, type "y" to instruct the utility to create the `.bst` file. :-)

Back to the (relatively) simple task of suppressing the string `pp.` in front of page ranges:

- Find the file `chicago.bst` in your TeX distribution, make a copy, and name the copy (say) `mychicago.bst`. Do not edit an original file directly.
- Open the file `mychicago.bst` in a plain-text editor.
- Find the function `format.pages` (ca. l. 680 in my copy of the bst file)
- A few lines down from the function's header line, locate the lines

  ```
      { "pp.\ " pages n.dashify tie.or.space.connect } % gnp - removed ()
      { "pp.\ " pages tie.or.space.connect }
  ```

  and replace them with

  ```
      { pages n.dashify tie.or.space.connect } % gnp - removed ()
      { pages tie.or.space.connect }
  ```
- Save the file, and start using it via the instruction `\bibliographystyle{mychicago}`.

That said, I really do recommend that you run the `makebst` utility and, when answering some of the prompts, simply specify that *no* `pp.` strings should be used.

Answer (score 1):

You can remove the "pp." and "p." from single entries by adding

```
pagination = {none}
```

to the bibliography entry, i.e. inside a @book or so.

Comment: With a "real" example as an entry with your solution, your answer will be better `;-)`

Comment: Does your answer pertain to a bibtex-based or a biblatex-based solution?

Comment: Oops, I use `biblatex`, sorry. I wrote more extensively in a [question about citing classics](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/31286/how-do-i-cite-classical-works-with-biblatex) on how to use this, just wanted to add it here as well as to reach more people, but in doing so did not properly notice the difference between `bibtex` and `biblatex`.