# Bibilography handling of page numbers in inproceedings vs article

Tags: bibliographies

When using the alpha bibliography style, the page numbers are listed differently in `inproceedings` and `article`: While `article` just lists the page numbers, `inproceedings` writes "pages...". How can I make both handle page numbers the same way (optimally, both should just omit the word "pages" like in `article`).

An example:
[image]

Where the bib file is:

```
@inproceedings{salam,
  author       = {Salam, Abdus},
  editor       = {Svartholm, Nils},
  title        = {Weak and Electromagnetic Interactions},
  date         = {1968},
  location     = {Stockholm},
  pages        = {367-377},
}

@article{morris1984early,
  title={An early program proof by Alan Turing},
  author={Morris, F Lockwood and Jones, Cliff B},
  journal={Annals of the History of Computing},
  volume={6},
  number={2},
  pages={139--143},
  year={1984},
  publisher={IEEE}
}
```

And the tex file for reproduction of this problem:
\documentclass[english]{article}

```
\usepackage{natbib}

\begin{document}
test
\cite{morris1984early}
\cite{salam}
\bibliographystyle{alpha}
\bibliography{mybib}

\end{document}
```

Comment: I daresay that the supposed inconsistency in the treatment of the contents of the `pages` field across two entry types -- `@article` and `@inproceedings` -- is neither a problem nor something worth fixing (say, by modifying the code in the `inproceedings` function in the file `alpha.bst`). To the contrary, there's an excellent reason for why the `inproceedings` function prefixes the string "pages" to the `pages` field: to resolve ambiguity over what the numbers might mean. For instances, for entries of types `@inproceedings`, one might also find information about chapters and volume numbers.

Comment: To *really* get the bibliography right, you could start by encasing the substring "Alan Turing" in a pair of curly braces, to prevent BibTeX from changing it to "alan turing". (Check out your screenshot to see what I'm talking about.) Another place where an immediate improvement might be noticed by your readers is if you provided the currently missing field `booktitle = {Elementary Particle Physics}` in the `salam` entry. Observe that in your screenshot, the `editor` isn't shown because the entry is currently lacking the `booktitle` field. Finally, do change `location` to `address`.

Comment: Related answer by Mico: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/113691/remove-pp-from-references-produced-by-chicago-style-re-position-page-numbers. But this behavior is standard, journal articles get the `volume(number):firstpage-lastpage` syntax while other entry types use the string `pages` or `pp.`. You will find this in other published papers that use `natbib` (i.e., _a lot_ of published papers), so you will be in good company when you keep the defaults.