# Bibliography reference has a more recent reprinting

Tags: biblatex, biber

Using BibLatex/Biber+alphabetic bibliography style, I would like to note, simply for the convenience of the reader, that a book has been reprinted more recently by another publisher. Something like the following is what I'm after:

```
 [Sne51] Ian N. Sneddon. Fourier Transforms. New York: McGraw-Hill, 1951. Reprinted
         New York: Dover Publications, 1995.
```

What is the recommended way of doing this?

I thought note={} would do the job but the "Reprinted ..." info ends up in the middle of the reference. Any guidance would be gratefully appreciated.

Comment: Welcome to tex.sx.  Not suggesting this as a duplicate, but this answer addresses a similar situation:  https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/31344

Comment: @barbarabeeton, thank you very much. I wasn't aware of the origdate and origpublisher entry fields. This is a very good option.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The semantically nicest way to do this goes via the `related` functionality.

By default `biblatex` will then also show the title again (but that could be changed if desired).

```
\documentclass[british]{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{babel}
\usepackage{csquotes}

\usepackage[backend=biber, style=alphabetic]{biblatex}

\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@book{sneddon,
  author      = {Ian N. Sneddon},
  title       = {Fourier Transforms},
  year        = {1951},
  publisher   = {McGraw-Hill},
  location    = {New York},
  related     = {sneddon:reprint},
  relatedtype = {reprint},
}
@book{sneddon:reprint,
  author    = {Ian N. Sneddon},
  title     = {Fourier Transforms},
  year      = {1995},
  publisher = {Dover Publications},
  location  = {New York},
}
\end{filecontents}
\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}
\addbibresource{biblatex-examples.bib}

\begin{document}
Lorem \autocite{sigfridsson,sneddon}

\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

[image: Ian N. Sneddon. Fourier Transforms. New York: McGraw-Hill, 1951. Repr. Fourier Transforms. New York: Dover Publications, 1995.]

---

For a one-off it can be easier to just put these kind of things into the `addendum` field. Unlike the `note` field, `addendum` should appear close to the very end of the entry.

```
\documentclass[british]{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{babel}
\usepackage{csquotes}

\usepackage[backend=biber, style=alphabetic]{biblatex}

\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@book{sneddon,
  author      = {Ian N. Sneddon},
  title       = {Fourier Transforms},
  year        = {1951},
  publisher   = {McGraw-Hill},
  location    = {New York},
  addendum    = {Reprinted
                 New York: Dover Publications, 1995},
  relatedtype = {reprint},
}
\end{filecontents}
\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}
\addbibresource{biblatex-examples.bib}

\begin{document}
Lorem \autocite{sigfridsson,sneddon}

\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

[image: Ian N. Sneddon. Fourier Transforms. New York: McGraw-Hill, 1951. Reprinted New York: Dover Publications, 1995.]

Comment: Thank you kindly @moewe. I can see both of these options having their places.