# Cite classical works (Aristotle) Bekker-style with footnote-dw style

Tags: biblatex-dw

I'm using footnote-dw for my dissertation, which includes some classical works. For those, I'd like to ideally:

1. Use Bekker reference: Aristotle, Poet. 1451a35.
2. The first mention, I want to give a note: All quotes from the Poetics are cited after [edition].

I found this question, and was trying to use the solution by "jon", which uses no additional packages, but defines a new command: `\newcommand{\metaphys}[1]{\emph{Met.}\@ #1\nocite{ross1924}\mancite}%`. But that doesn't work, latex gives me an error about "nocite".

Besides doing what I want manually (probably for No 2 the solution is just a simple footnote), is there a good, clean solution for this? Is there a way to adapt jon's solution for footnote-dw?

Comment: The link seems to have been omitted from the question, but I'm guessing you are referring to https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/31286/35864. Can you show us exactly what you tried and how it did not work for you? I naively tried https://gist.github.com/moewew/7ff15024f87b294ee35ea2bd86527977 and that worked in principle.

Comment: Oh, I for got to post the link, but that's the one! Unlike in your example, I'm using biblatex style "footnote-dw". I get the error: `Use of \nocite doesn't match its definition.` I'm thinking maybe footnote-dw changes `\nocite` in some way? Also, I defined the new command within the document, right before the first time I needed it, not in the preamble.

Comment: Even if I change `style=authoryear` in my example document to `style=footnote-dw` I cannot reproduce an error.

Comment: It's weird, it went away, maybe some stale aux files.